# Вопрос про вложенный SELECT

Tags: sql

Изучаю *SQL*

Пишу *SQL-запрос*:

```
SELECT mak FROM
  (SELECT mak, ram, speed FROM Prod WHERE mak = 'gr' ) t
WHERE t.ram = (SELECT MAX(t.ram) FROM t)
```

Получаю ответ:

> Invalid object name 't'

В чем суть, кто-нибудь может пояснить? и как это исправить?

Comment: Странный у вас какой-то запрос. Я и так скажу что он вам вернет 'gr'

Comment: мне надо из всех mak='gr' вывести все mak с наибольшим ram

Comment: Так оно вам и выведет все gr. Независимо от того есть там ram или нет. По сути ваш вопрос равнозначен "Мне надо узнать номер ящика, в котором лежит красный шарик, из всех шариков, которые я взял из второго ящика"

Comment: Судя по запросу, вам понадобится CTE: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_common_table_expressions_cte.html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

По сути ваш вопрос решается без всяких вложений

```
SELECT * FROM Prod WHERE mak = 'gr' ORDER BY ram DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Т.е. выбираем все записи у которых в поле mak стоит значение gr. Потом сортируем полученные записи по убыванию значения в поле ram. Т.е. в самом начале будет строка у которой ram максимально для всех gr. А c помощью LIMIT ограничиваем выдачу именно этой строкой с MAX(ram)